# How do I join these 3 tables and make my Select query work?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

review_shared:

```
review_shared_id    cat_id    user_id     contact_id
19                   5        10276       10275
20                   5        10276       10277
21                   5        10276       10273
15                   6        10279       10277
```

category:

```
cat_id    user_id    cat_name
  3        10278        A
  4        10279        B
  5        10276        C
  6        10279        D
```

I carry out my query with:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM review_shared 
  JOIN category 
    ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
 WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ?
";
```

With `review_shared.contact_id` as `10277`, the above would give me:

```
review_shared.                                 category.
review_shared_id  cat_id  user_id  contact_id  cat_id  user_id  cat_name
    20                5       10276    10277       5       10276    C
    15                6       10279    10277       6       10279    D
```

Now I have a third table, `contacts`:

```
contact_auto_inc   user_id  contact_id
1                   10278    10273
2                   10277    10276
3                   10261    10285
```

if the `contacts` table has a row with `user_id` as `10277` and `contact_id` as the `user_id` value in `review_shared`  table then I want to return these values. So in the case above the result would be (with `review_shared.contact_id = ?` as `10277`):

```
review_shared.                                 category.
        review_shared_id  cat_id     user_id  contact_id  cat_id  user_id  cat_name  contact_auto_inc   user_id  contact_id
            20                5       10276    10277       5       10276    C          2                 10277    10276
```

This is the statement I am using but it doesn't seem to be be working:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM review_shared 
  JOIN category 
    ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
  JOIN contacts 
    ON review_shared.contact_id = contacts.user_id 
   AND contacts.contact_id = review_shared.user_id
 WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ?
";
```

Comment: Your application code isn't going to know the difference between user_id and user_id in the resulting array :-(

Comment: Loose this line `AND contacts.contact_id = review_shared.user_id`

Comment: @RiggsFollyYes that was it exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have an error on the contact join:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM review_shared 
  JOIN category 
    ON review_shared.cat_id = category.cat_id 
  JOIN contacts 
    ON review_shared.contact_id = contacts.contact_id
 WHERE review_shared.contact_id = ?
";
```

Comment: I think there's a type in your code: `ON review_shared.contact_id = contacts.user_id` gives the desired result.